# Set dynamically the initial value of a slicer

Tags: powerbi

I have a slicer with a date field and I'd like to set the initial values of the range
dynamically.

The left position would be `today - 7 days` and the right position
would be `today`. Can I do it in `Power BI`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the slicer to be of relative date type:

[image]

Which gives you more options:

[image]

But you cannot set default relative values for the "regular" date slicer.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/desktop-slicer-filter-date-range